# combine two select query result on some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, inner-join

I have to get result from two select queries where second query result is conditioned on first query result.

```
Table 1: tbl1
EndDate       PEL   FL
4/24/2015      2    4
6/12/2015      3    5
8/9/2015       4    7



  Table 2 : tbl2
    EndDate      CumEL    CumFL
    3/20/2015      3       6
    4/10/2015      2       9
    4/15/2015      1       2
    5/10/2015      4       1
    5/21/2015      5       5
    6/12/2015      8       7
    6/15/2015      1       2
    7/6/2015       4       1
    7/11/2015      5       5
    8/9/2015       8       7
```

I want to join these two table on below criteria :

```
Select tbl1.* from tbl1
JOIN 
Select Sum(CumEL),Sum(CumFL) from tbl2 where tbl2.EndDate <= tbl1.EndDate
```

Desired Output:

```
EndDate     PEL   FL  CumEL  CumFL
4/24/2015    2    4     6      17
6/12/2015    3    5     23     30
8/9/2015     4    7     41     45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a cross apply (though a join would also work, it just gets a bit more complicated to write):

```
SELECT tbl1.EndDate, tbl1.PEL, tbl1.FL, C.CumEL, C.CumFL
FROM tbl1
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT SUM(CumEL) AS CumEL, SUM(CumFL) AS CumFL
    FROM tbl2
    WHERE tbl2.EndDate <= tbl1.EndDate
) AS C;
```

Comment: i had used it before but did't strike to my mind. thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `left join` like this

```
select tbl1.EndDate, tbl1.PEL, tbl1.FL,
        SUM(Coalesce(tbl2.CumEL,0) as CumEL,
        SUM(Coalesce(tbl2.CumFL,0)) as CumFL,
from tbl1 
left join tbl1 on tbl1.EndDate >= tbl2.EndDate
group by tbl1.EndDate, tbl1.PEL, tbl1.FL
```